# Launch AlertDialog after receiving message

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

In my app I want AlertDialog to apeear, when SMS is recieved from 1902.
I have BroadcastReciever Running

```
public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver {

// Get the object of SmsManager
final SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Retrieves a map of extended data from the intent.
    final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    try {

        if (bundle != null) {

            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {

                SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                String phoneNumber = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                String message = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

                Log.i("SmsReceiver", "senderNum: " + phoneNumber + "; message: " + message);

                if (TextUtils.equals(currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress(), "1902")) {
                    // Show Alert

                    MainActivity actv1= new MainActivity();
                    actv1.Dialog(message);
                }

            } // end for loop
        } // bundle is null


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SmsReceiver", "Exception smsReceiver" +e);

    }
}
```

And In main activity I have Void:

```
 public void Dialog(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Title123");
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("HEY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

        }
    });
    Log.i("test2", message);
    builder.show();
}
```

But when SMS is recieved nothing happenes, can experts tell What is the problem?

Comment: Have you checked if this is called or not ?

Comment: Is your senderNum: and message: showing in LogCat ?

Comment: Sendernum is shown, but Log.i("test2", message); is not

Comment: currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress() gives you what value ?

Comment: It is alright,problem is in MainActivity actv1= new MainActivity();
                    actv1.Dialog(message);

Answer (score 0):

You have created MyActivity to use as a Context instead of already provided context

```
if (TextUtils.equals(currentMessage.getOriginatingAddress(), "1902")) 
{
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Title123");
    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton("HEY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
        {

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

**Note**

```
MainActivity actv1= new MainActivity(); // This is wrong
```

You can't create any Activity yourself using new operator, Android handle creation of Activity you just have to pass the intent to create activity.

Comment: Android handle creation of Activity you just have to pass the intent to create activity. Could you explain more easylly please?

Comment: Take a look at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html you will get it better :)

Comment: If this worked for your question, please mark this as a correct answer :)

Comment: I cant understand where I should get this context
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

Comment: from here - public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {...}